# xml file not reading when running the jar file from dist folder after cleaning and building in netbeans

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

This is my code.

```
File file = new File("src/qrcodescanner/xmlpac/"+filename);
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder(); 
document = db.parse(file);
document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it can't be red it most probably isn't where you expect it to be. Judging by the code you posted I suppose that your xml file is intended to reside inside your jar/package structure.

This is my test project structure:

```
src
 |-- main
     |-- java
         |-- mypackage
                 MyCode.java
                 MyResource.xml
```

The corresponding generated jar file is located at `target/` directory and looks like this:

```
 mypackage
     MyCode.class
     MyResource.xml
```

`MyResource.xml` looks like this:

```
<a>b</a>
```

`MyCode.java` looks like this:

```
public class MyCode {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {        
    String packagePath= "/mypackage/MyResource.xml";
    String myPath ="src/main/java"+packagePath;
    File f = new File(myPath);
    System.out.println(f.exists());        
    InputStream is = Class.class.getResourceAsStream(packagePath);                
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder(); 
    Document d = db.parse(is);
    System.out.println(d.getElementsByTagName("a").item(0).getTextContent());         
    }    
}
```

When run it prints:

```
true
b
```

Method [getResourceAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) is used for loading resources from inside the JAR. Hope that helps.

Comment: But I am getting an Exception:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: InputStream cannot be null

Comment: that means that you have a mistake in your packagePath or that the file is not packed in the JAR. check your path's and open up the JAR and make sure that the file is inside the JAR on the exact place and with the exact name as analogously specified in packagePath variable.

Comment: Would you help me answering the the following question.(How can i give a jar file to another person who not having java installed in his system?)

Comment: you can copy it as any other file, but if the host machine doesn't have JRE installed (download it [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre7-downloads-1880261.html) or [here](http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp?locale=en)) you can not run it, you can just open it like a zip file.